# Unable to run aliases with cmder on command line - aliases not recognised

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, cmd.exe, alias

I am using cmder on Windows 10, I have some aliases in the user-aliases.cmd file, I created a new alias using the alias command on the command line and there are some that were already in the file such as history.

When I try to use an alias on the cmder command line I get the following error e.g. for history:

```
'history' is not recognised as an internal or external command
```

I'm able to autocomplete the aliases that are in the aliases file but they don't run the command that they should, they show the error above. I'd like to fix this so that the aliased command actually runs and would like some help please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cmder Github documentation](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder#bashexeminttyexe-aliases), you may need to add your aliases to different files depending on the shell you are using.

For example, if you use Bash.exe or Mintty.exe, instead of adding aliases to user_aliases.cmd you should add your aliases to the user_profile.sh file located in %CMDER_ROOT%\config\user_profile.sh

Alternatively for Bash specifically, you can also add aliases to your bashrc file. On Windows, this file is probably in $HOME/.bashrc